# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException, Date could not be parsed

Tags: java, json, date, spring-boot

I am trying to create an application using springboot-java,
front end as html/css/javascript. I get the below error while doing a post to create an employee record. I am passing a join date which is causing the error.

> ```
> failed - {"readyState":4,
>     "responseText":"{\"timestamp\":1515066928232,
>         \"status\":500,
>         \"error\":\"Internal Server Error\",
>         \"exception\":\"java.time.format.DateTimeParseException\",
>         \"message\":\"Text '01-17-2018' could not be parsed at index 0\",
>         \"path\":\"/employee/\"}",
>     "responseJSON":{"timestamp":1515066928232,
>         "status":500,
>         "error":"Internal Server Error",
>         "exception":"java.time.format.DateTimeParseException",
>         "message":"Text '01-17-2018' could not be parsed at index 0",
>         "path":"/employee/"},
>     "status":500,
>     "statusText":"error"}
> ```

Below is the code I use in java:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7314008048174880868L;
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy");

    private Integer organisation;
    private String empName;
    private String joinDate;
    private String gender;
    private String designation;
    private String email;
    public EmployeeDto(){
    }

    public EmployeeDto(Integer organisation, String empName, String joinDate, String gender,
            String designation, String email) {
        super();
        this.organisation = organisation;
        this.empName = empName;
        this.joinDate = joinDate;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.designation = designation;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Employee buildEmployee(){
        return new Employee(this.empName,LocalDate.parse(this.joinDate),this.gender,this.designation,this.email);
    }
```

I use the below date converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
        return (locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
        return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
    }
}
```

I am unable to find the root cause....

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. You would have found many examples from which you could have copied working code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `buildEmployee()` I think you want `LocalDate.parse(this.joinDate, DATE_FORMAT)` instead of `LocalDate.parse(this.joinDate)`.

One often posted link here on Stack Overflow is [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). In that blog post the *first* tip is to turn on compiler warnings and read them carefully. Putting your code into my Eclipse produces the following warning:

> The value of the field EmployeeDto.DATE_FORMAT is not used

This may cause you to wonder why `DATE_FORMAT` is not used and why you wanted to have it there in the first place. Which in turn could inspire you to use it as intended, which fixes your error.